# Segmentation fault: 0x0000000000000001 in ?? () trying to compile/link under Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have a suite of software written in 'C'. This is normally compiled using acc and run on a UNIX Solaris system but I have been given the task of getting it to run under Linux on an x86_64 box.

I am not particularly familiar with gcc or Linux but I have managed to get the code to compile with just a minimum of changes to remove warnings that weren't there under Solaris. I am using the following compile command (invoked from a script, hence the environment variables):

```
/usr/bin/gcc -L/tmp/lib -L/tmp/usr/lib -c -fPIC -g -I$WORKING_DIR $INCLUDE $WORKING_DIR/$FILE
```

Most of the source is then placed in shared (.so) libraries, also via script, using the following command:

```
ld $GLOSS_SUB_DIR/$REL_DIR/obj/$PREFIX*".o" -G -o $GLOSS_SUB_DIR/$REL_DIR/lib/$LIB$NEW_MIN_VER_NO
```

A sample makefile for an executable called 'gsproc' is as follows:

```
CONTROL_NO = $(shell awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} /control/ {printf "%s%s", $$3,$$4} END{}' $$GLOSS_DIR/subenv_list)

CTRL_PATH = $(GLOSS_DIR)/control/$(CONTROL_NO)

OBJECTS = $(CTRL_PATH)/nolib/gsproc.o  \
          $(CTRL_PATH)/nolib/w_bkg_shared.o

LIBS    = -lcontrolw \
          -lsharew \
          -lsybdb64


gsproc: $(OBJECTS)
     gcc -shared -fPIC -o $(TMP_DIR)/gsproc \
         -L $(SYBASE)/$(SYBASE_OCS)/devlib \
          $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -lm -lc –lnsl
```

I have been successful in compiling and then linking all of the code but every executable now falls over immediately on startup with a segmentation fault and core dump. All I get from gdb is:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-50.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /gloss_env/GLSLAZ_TST2/control/C2.0.0/bin/gsproc...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /gloss_env/GLSLAZ_TST2/control/C2.0.0/bin/gsproc 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
```

So it doesn't look like the problem is with the code, as such. Presumably I am doing something wrong with my compiler or linker options.

Comment: Use gcc, not ld for linking.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did consider that but I thought gcc just calls ld anyway? I've inherited a fairly involved set of scripts which handle the compilation and population of the shared libraries. Depending on the prefix on the source file the objects have to go into different libraries so I was trying not to have to make too big a change to the current mechanism.

If I were to populate the .so library via gcc, what is the command line option to use? How do I tell it which library the object needs to be loaded into?

Comment: gcc does call ld, but with internal options applied that you're otherwise missing if using ld directly. You should probably read this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html. It would be best if you used an actual build system for this though, which would ensure a correct build. I recommend CMake (http://www.cmake.org) which allows you do use the same build system on all platforms. Automake (http://www.gnu.org/software/automake) is another alternative, which works together with Autoconf (http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf). In general, use CMake if you  can.

Comment: Thanks for that. My brief is to make minimal changes to the existing system. Just enough to get it to work under Linux so, unless I have to, I'd rather not replace the internal build system we have. 

I've been doing some trial and error and it looks like the problem might be because of the -shared option in the make file. One of the executables doesn't use libraries and once I  removed -shared it worked fine. When I took it off one of the other executables that does use libraries I got a bunch of undefined reference errors which I reckon, once I fix, should resolve the problem. Here's hoping!

Comment: Replacing the current build system with something sane is not a bad thing. Your current one doesn't even detect how to link binaries correctly on a given platform.

Comment: @user2311565 Can you post an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This Makefile rule / gcc command

```
gsproc: $(OBJECTS)
     gcc -shared -fPIC -o $(TMP_DIR)/gsproc \
         -L $(SYBASE)/$(SYBASE_OCS)/devlib \
          $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -lm -lc –lnsl
```

makes a shared object namde gsproc (without the normal lib prefix and .so suffix). An executable and a library is the same fileformat in many operating systems, with the side-effect that you can try to run a shared-library as an executable. But the result is usually what you see, instant crash etc.